# Why does my TextView show up without borders in a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

This is my layout XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border" />

    <TextView android:text="ahahah 2!"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the border definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#4fa5d5"/>
</shape>
```

This makes a horizontal line appear between the `TextView`s but I'm expecting a border around the text of the `TextView`s themselves. How do I make that happen?

Comment: May be just use `wrap_content` for the height attribute at your 2nd TextView

Comment: remove this from View : android:background="@drawable/border"  and provide color for that, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply define it in `Text View` itself.

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:text="Hello World!" />
```

**Change your xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="22sp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="22sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border" />

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:text="ahahah 2!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:background="@drawable/border" 
         android:text="desired text"
         android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
```

Try this background xml

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <shape 
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
            android:shape="rectangle">

           <stroke android:color="@color/colorPrimary" 
            android:width="1dp"/>
           <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
           <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
         </shape>
```

Have your textview with margin according  to design.

Comment: Please elaborate answer .

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="22sp" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="22sp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you apply padding on Textview and remove View in between Textviews that will work fine ,try this code.... it's working

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="ahahah 2!" />
```